# Trying to use dnsmasq on snow leopard for iphone development

Tags: iphone, macos, osx-snow-leopard, dnsmasq

I'm doing some mobile development on my iMac running snow-leopard and I wish to be able to access the virtual hosts configured on the iMac on the mobile devices on my LAN. So I've installed Dnsmasq through Macports. I think I've got it set up correctly and I believe it's running, but I just get a 'server not found' error if I try to access one of the virtual hosts from my iPhone.

So, my iMac has the IP 192.168.0.111 this is where Apache lives and the host `example.dev` resolves properly to the dev website on the iMac. If I run the iOS simulator on the iMac, this also works. The iMac is connected to the LAN over ethernet, the iphone over Wifi, which cannot see `example.dev` despite my putting the iMac into the iPhone's WiFi's DNS settings.

dnsmasq appears to be running:

```
ps aux | grep dnsmasq
dm        913   0.0  0.0  2435120    556 s000  R+   12:17pm   0:00.00 grep dnsmasq   
nobody     895   0.0  0.0  2435060    600   ??  Ss   12:09pm   0:00.01 /opt/local/sbin/dnsmasq -k
```

My /opt/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf is below:

```
#interface=en0
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf
address=/.dev/127.0.0.1
```

I've tried it with and without the `interface` line to no effect, I've restarted dnsmasq using `sudo port unload dnsmasq` and then `sudo port load dnsmasq` to no difference.

I've tried pinging any arbitrary host, some false, some correct (e.g. pwoefojpo.dev  / foo.dev / example.dev ) from the iMac and I'd expect all of these to ping 127.0.0.1 but only the valid hosts (as in `/etc/hosts`) actually allow me to ping 127.0.0.1.

The LAN is a simple Virgin Media Superhub, which contains a number of devices over Wifi and Cat5.

If anyone can shed any light, I'm grateful.